# Clock generator is not oscillating on the given XTAL's frequency

Tags: noise, clock, crystal

I created a PCB which needs to have a solid and precious clock source.
For this purpose I used a Dual Inverter with Schmitt trigger (NC7WZ14).

[image: CLKI]

Now CLKI seems to generate 66kHz square signals (measured by an oscilloscope at the point of CLKI).

[image: Scope image]

Why is this circuit not generating 11.0592MHz for me?

EDIT:

Referenced from: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/crystal.html, at section "CMOS Crystal Oscillator".

Thanks.

Comment: Why R8? Feels like you're mixing Opamp and Schmitt-Trigger circuits

Comment: I found it online. What do you recommend for me to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a Schmitt trigger for your inverter.  An oscillator like the one you show in your schematic depends on the inverter acting like a linear amplifier due to the feedback, and this is not possible for a Schmitt trigger inverter.

EDIT:

Take a look at [this reference](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8053-D.PDF) which explains using CMOS gates in oscillators.

Comment: You suggest me to change the inverter to a non-schmitt trigger one?

Comment: Yes.  Take a look at the reference I added to the answer.

Comment: +1 Not only non-ST but it should be an **unbuffered** type.

Comment: Thank you. Will make an update once I got the new part and tried out.

Comment: I have successfully made an oscillator using standard buffered inverters, but I took advantage of a 'feature' that they had issues with ground bounce. (Part was 74LCX04).

Comment: Using NL27WZU04 as suggested by crj11 was solved my problem. Thank you!